# Simulate '&' likewise terminal custom shell

Tags: c, unix, terminal

I'm trying to recreate my own terminal in C, and I'm in the part of running a process in the background:
For example, in Linux terminal, if I type

> ivo@ivo-Surface-Pro-6:~$ firefox &

It immediately prints and returns to terminal this:

> [1] 29093

> ivo@ivo-Surface-Pro-6:~$

Mine doesnt do this, it waits till I close windows to return to the terminal, how can I handle this?

> ivo@ivo-Surface-Pro-6:/home/ivo/Documents/SO1/soi-myshell-Ivoo25$ firefox &

> [1] 28505

If I close firefox once open, it return this:

> [1] Done

How can I manage to simulate this? Besides everything, this is the part of the code where Im handling this

```
    void execute(char **tokens, int token_Size, int *blk)
     {
    pid_t pid, wpid;

    int status;
    int result;

    int flag;
    int isPipe;
    int pipeAm = 0;
    int output;
    int input;

    int isAmper;

    int pipefd[2], pipefd2[2];

    if (needs_amper(tokens, token_Size) > 0)
    {
        *blk += 1;
    }

    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); //Silently (and portably) reap children

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("Fork:");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) //Child 1
    {
        signal(SIGTSTP, handleSigtstp);
        signal(SIGCONT, handleSigCont);
        isAmper = needs_amper(tokens, token_Size);
        output = needs_out_redir(tokens, token_Size);
        input = needs_in_redir(tokens, token_Size);
        isPipe = needs_pipe(tokens, token_Size);
        pipeAm = needs_pipe2(tokens, token_Size);

        if (isAmper != -1)
        {
            printf("[%d] %d \n", *blk, getppid()); //-> [blk] is the job number asigned to the job
            tokens[isAmper] = NULL;
            
        }

        if (strcmp(tokens[0], "echo") == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; tokens[i]; i++)
            {
                printf("%s ", tokens[i]);
            }
        }

        flag = 0;

        if (output != -1)
        {
            redirect_output(tokens, output);
            tokens[output] = NULL;
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (input != -1)
        {
            redirect_input(tokens, input);
            tokens[input] = NULL;
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (isPipe != -1)
        {
            create_pipe(tokens, output, input, isPipe, pipefd, pipefd2, &pipeAm, &pid, &wpid);
        }

        if (flag || isPipe == -1)
        {
            execvp(tokens[0], tokens);
            perror("Unkown Command:");
            exit(1);
        }

        //  exit(0);
    }
    else // Main (parent) process after fork succeeds
    {
        while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0)
            ; // this way, the father waits for all the child processes
        result = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        if (result == 1) //If the process terminated correctly, result returns 0.
        {
            printf("The child process terminated with an error!.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `How can I solve this? ` What is "this" exactly? You want your shell to receive asynchronous notification when child exits? Either trap SIGCHLD or poll on waitpid.

Comment: @KamilCuk What I want is to simulate the terminall function that when I type firefox & it opens it and returns immediately to the terminal again

Comment: So just remove `wait` and `waitpid`...

Comment: But then for other commands the terminal starts failing... @KamilCuk

Comment: so you have differentiate which commands have `&` on the end and which does not have it and make a decision if you should `wait` or not for the background process...

Comment: I managed to do so (I think) by adding a flag in my execute() function, which is 1 if there was an &, or 0 if it wasnt, the thing is that if i do so, I can get to imitate it, but when I type another command (for example ps) I cant get the terminal to show me the prompt again @KamilCuk

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue ? What was the problem ?